# How to show error message from ajax response of api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, response

i  have sent api request using  jquery ajax i am getting ajax response like this

Array ( [consumer_key] => ada691a715307861907d65d36d [consumer_secret] => a75e40ec1530786190b62316d1 [consumer_nonce] => 1537011049789 [consumer_device_id] => ldx0EWMCl3hNhJWCRIdPVveLy [consumer_url] => processregistration ) {"success":"0","data":[],"message":"Email address is already exist"}

i would like to show error message  if response contains "Email address is already exist" otherwise alert Message shuold be successfully submitted

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("submitted!");
   
   
   
    var customers_firstname=$("#customers_firstname").val();
        var customers_lastname=$("#customers_lastname").val();
         var customers_telephone=$("#customers_telephone").val();
          var email=$("#email").val();
    
    
  var d = new Date();
    var consumer_nonce = d.getTime();
  
  U=url+'api/save_reg';
  //alert(consumer_nonce);
  //exit;
  //var ul="{{ url('/backend/api/save_reg') }}";
 
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url+'api/save_reg',
       data:$("#postcontent").serialize(),
 /* data:{
       customers_firstname:customers_firstname,
       customers_lastname:customers_lastname,
     customers_telephone:customers_telephone,
      email:email,
      password:password
      },*/
       headers: {
        
        "consumer-key": consumer_key, 
  "consumer-secret": consumer_secret, 
  "consumer-nonce": consumer_nonce, 
  "consumer-device-id": consumer_device_id,  
    },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $(".post_submitting").show().html("<center><img src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif'/></center>");
        },success:function(response){ 
  
  

    alert(response);
    
 
  
  //-- alert(response[1]); 
            //alert(response);
   //response = response.toJSON();
   //alert(response);
            $("#return_update_msg").html(response); 
            $(".post_submitting").fadeOut(1000);                
        }
    });
   
    
   
   
  }
 });
```

```html
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')
    
    @section('title','Home')
     
    @section('body')
    
    

    
   
<!-- Main Container  -->
<div class="main-container container">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="row">
   <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="title">Register Account</h2>
    <p>If you already have an account with us, please login at the <a href="#">login page</a>.</p>
    <div id="return_update_msg" class="return_update_msg">j</div>
                <div class="post_submitting"></div>
                
                <form name="postcontent" class="cmxform" id="postcontent" >

     <fieldset id="account">
      <legend>Your Personal Details</legend>
      
      <div class="form-group required">
                    
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="customers_firstname">First Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="customers_firstname" minlength="2"  placeholder="First Name" id="customers_firstname" class="form-control">
                                <span id="customers_firstname_error"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="customers_lastname">Last Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="customers_lastname" minlength="2"  placeholder="Last Name" id="customers_lastname" class="form-control">
                                 <span id="customers_lastname_error"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="E-Mail" id="email" class="form-control">
                                 <span id="email_error"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-telephone">Mobile Number</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" name="customers_telephone"  placeholder="Telephone" id="customers_telephone" class="form-control">
                                  <span id="customers_telephone_error"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
     </fieldset>
     
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Password</legend>
      <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control">
                                  <span id="password_error"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="confirm_password">Password Confirm</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password"  placeholder="Password Confirm" id="confirm_password" class="form-control">
                                 <span id="password_confirm_error"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
      <span id="success_message"></span>
     <div class="buttons">
       <input class="submit btn btn-primary" id="save_buttonk" type="submit" value="Submit">
       <!--<input type="submit" id="save_button" value="Continue" class="btn btn-primary">-->
      </div>
                        </form>
     </div>
   
   </div>
  </div>
        <br />
<!-- //Main Container -->

 @endsection
   @section('pagescript')
   
   

   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/frontend/qshopee')}}/js/registration.js"></script>
   
   <script>

$().ready(function() {
  // validate the comment form when it is submitted
  $("#commentForm").validate();
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#postcontent").validate({
   rules: {
    //customers_firstname: "required",
    //customers_lastname: "required",
    /*username: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 2
    },*/
    customers_firstname: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 2
    },
    customers_lastname: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 2
    },
    password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5
    },
    confirm_password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5,
     equalTo: "#password"
    },
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    },
    /*topic: {
     required: "#newsletter:checked",
     minlength: 2
    },
    agree: "required"*/
   },
   messages: {
    //customers_firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
    //customers_lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
    /*username: {
     required: "Please enter a username",
     minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },*/
    customers_firstname: {
     required: "Please enter a firstname",
     minlength: "Your firstname must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },
    customers_lastname: {
     required: "Please enter a lastname",
     minlength: "Your lastname must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },
    password: {
     required: "Please provide a password",
     minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    confirm_password: {
     required: "Please provide a password",
     minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
     equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
    },
    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    /*agree: "Please accept our policy",
    topic: "Please select at least 2 topics"*/
   }
  });

 
 
 });
 
   </script>
    
   @stop
```

Comment: I think its best if you include some working code from your side. That would help us help you.

Comment: few clarifications : does `success:0` always imply an `error` ? In other words does `success: 1` always mean its successful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (response.indexOf('Email address is already exist') > -1)
{
alert("Email Already Registered");
 }
 else
 {
 alert("Registration Successful");
```